# The dual cone of $\{(x, t) \,|\, ||x||_1 \le t\}$

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

In the course slides for the Stanford Convex Optimization course by Boyd it states that if

$$K=\{(x, t) \,|\, ||x||_1 \le t\}$$

then its dual cone is

$$K^* =\{(x, t) \,|\, ||x||_\infty \le t\}$$

Why is that?

If $x = (-t, 0)$ and $y = (t, 0)$ then $x \in K$ and $y \in K^*$ but $x^ty = -t^2$, which is negative, contrary to the definition of a dual cone.

Comment: Your example is a bit confused because of bad notation.  The elements of $K$ are vectors $(x,t)$ in $R^{n+1}$.  In your example, is $n=1$, or $n=2$?  The only way that a vector $(-t,0) \in K$ is if $n=1$ and $t=0$.